# Can read() from socket return EWOULDBLOCK?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, epoll

My code uses epoll for multiplexing. After EPOLLIN is encountered it reads one byte from ready socket.

```
read(fd, &onebyte, 1);
```

Can the above line return EWOULDBLOCK?

Comment: More precise: it can return -1 with errno set to EWOULDBLOCK.

Comment: Can't imagine situation when socket is ready for reading and still cant read one byte. Should have rephrased my question.

Comment: Here's a situation (from the select() man-page, but it may apply to epoll() as well):   "Under Linux, select() may report a socket file descriptor as "ready
       for reading", while nevertheless a subsequent read blocks.  This
       could for example happen when data has arrived but upon examination
       has wrong checksum and is discarded.  There may be other
       circumstances in which a file descriptor is spuriously reported as
       ready.  Thus it may be safer to use O_NONBLOCK on sockets that should not block."

Comment: Something could happen to the socket **after** the POLLIN was returned to the user process. (such as: arrival of a segment, needing the kernel to lock someof its buffers)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thanks for explanation

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,

> **Errors**:
>
> ...
>
> EAGAIN or **EWOULDBLOCK**
>
> The file descriptor fd refers to a socket and has been marked
>   nonblocking (O_NONBLOCK), and the read would block. POSIX.1-2001
>   allows either error to be returned for this case, and does not require
>   these constants to have the same value, so a portable application
>   should check for both possibilities

reference: 
[the read() man description](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read)

Comment: So, even if fd is ready for read and there is some data avaible, it can still return EWOULDBLOCK?

Comment: it is pretty straight forward, from the description,
you can understand more from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281468/write-to-the-client-returns-ewouldblock-when-server-is-slow

Comment: In principle it shouldn't block (or return EWOULDBLOCK), but in practice some implementations may occasionally do so anyway, so your code should be written such that it can handle that possibility.  (there's no penalty to handling that situation gracefully, and a definite penalty if you don't and it does happen)